# How to move point from X to Y?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm from a new family with React Native. I'm working with react-native-reanimated to move the point from X to Y. For now, I'm only moving it to Y, I don't know how to move it from Y to X.

Here is the source:
https://snack.expo.dev/@tiendung1601/app

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks all!!!

Comment: What do you mean ? You don't know hot to move a point horizontal?

Comment: Yes, move a point like this https://snack.expo.dev/@tiendung1601/activity-indicator

Answer (score 1):

You could approach that as [follows](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/chain-react-animation):

Example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withTiming,
  Easing,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const initialOffset = 200;

const ChainableAnimation = {
  duration: 800,
  animationSequence: [],
  addAnimation: (move = 50, direction: "x" | "y" = "x") => {
    ChainableAnimation.animationSequence.push({ move, direction });
  },
  createPromise: ({ move, direction, offset }) => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      const animation = withTiming(
        move,
        { duration: ChainableAnimation.duration, easing: Easing.cubic },
        (_finished) => {
          console.log("_finished: ", _finished);
        }
      );

      offset[direction].value = animation;

      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, ChainableAnimation.duration);
    });
  },
  startAnimation: (offset) => {
    ChainableAnimation.animationSequence.reduce(
      (previousPromise, sequence, index) => {
        return previousPromise.then(() => {
          return ChainableAnimation.createPromise({
            ...sequence,
            index,
            offset,
          });
        });
      },
      Promise.resolve()
    );
  },
};

export default function App() {
  const offsetX = useSharedValue(initialOffset);
  const offsetY = useSharedValue(initialOffset);

  const offset = {x: offsetX, y: offsetY};

  const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ translateX: offset.x.value }, { translateY: offset.y.value }],
  }));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // ChainableAnimation.duration = 1300;
    ChainableAnimation.addAnimation(-100, "x");
    ChainableAnimation.addAnimation(-100, "y");
    ChainableAnimation.addAnimation(100, "x");
    ChainableAnimation.addAnimation(100, "y");
    ChainableAnimation.startAnimation(offset);
  }, []);



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyles]} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "100%",
  },
  box: {
    height: 120,
    width: 120,
    backgroundColor: "#b58df1",
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
});
```